# Interface naming convention for method returning Task

Tags: c#, .net, interface, naming-conventions, async-await

Consider the following interface and implementations.

```
interface IService
{
    Task<string> GetAnswer(string question);
}

class SomeService : IService
{
    async Task<string> IService.GetAnswer(string question)
    {
        ... code using awaits ...
    }
}

class AnotherService : IService
{
    Task<string> IService.GetAnswer(string question)
    {
        return Task.FromResult("I have no idea.");
    }
}
```

According to [the Microsoft naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#BKMK_NamingConvention), should the interface method be named `GetAnswer` or `GetAnswerAsync`?

> By convention, you append "Async" to the names of methods that have an Async or async modifier.

The problem is that the first implementation uses the `async` modifier, indicating it should receive the "Async" method name suffix, but the second implementation does not use the `async` modifier, indicating it should not receive the "Async" method name suffix. The two method names in the implementations are forced to be the same by the interface, so I am forced to violate the naming conventions for one of the two classes.

Note I'm not looking for opinionated answers. Consider it multiple choice. :)

1. You should use the "Async" suffix because the naming conventions say so. (With reference.)
2. You should not use the "Async" suffix because the naming conventions say so. (With reference.)
3. The naming conventions don't say. (This will need to come from someone well-versed in them.)

Comment: a method of `HttpClient`: `public Task<string> GetStringAsync(string requestUri);`

Comment: I'm confused about why people are voting to close this question based on it being "primarily opinion based." It's an objective question about the contents of Microsoft's naming conventions. What I want to know is if I'm missing some section that talks about interface methods returning `Task` or if that's not mentioned at all in the naming conventions. That's not opinion-based.

Comment: I agree, conventions are not opinions.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Conventions are *absolutely* opinions.

Comment: @TimothyShields The fact that you're asking to have answers link to some opinions posted by someone else elsewhere instead of providing their own opinions doesn't change the fact that you're asking for opinions.  The fact that someone has grouped a number of opinions into a single document and called it a "convention" doesn't make it not an opinion, on top of the fact that choosing which convention to reference is as opinion based as the convention itself.

Comment: @Servy: if you're going to look at it that literally then there are many rules to be bent. Fact remains that a convention often counts as a rule so there is a concrete limit to the amount of discussion such a question can create.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel You can't just say, "I don't care that this is an opinion, I want to pretend that it's a fact even though it's not."  Naming conventions are things that people discuss endlessly, there certainly not something that you can say are unlikely to result in arguments, debates, extended discussions, etc.  In fact naming conventions and other aesthetic coding style conventions are some of the most controversial and long standing unconstructive debates throughout programming history.  This is the quintessential example of a subjective question that doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: @Servy The question "Do the Microsoft method naming conventions contain the world 'elephant'?" is an objective question that leaves no room for argument or debate. This question is no different: it's asking if the Microsoft method naming conventions contain a particular reference to interface methods returning tasks. I searched for it but didn't find it, so I asked here. I already got my answer so the pain is over anyway. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `XAsync` even when there isn't an `async` modifier as long as the method represents a complete task based asynchronous operation.

To be technical about it, the passage you quoted tells you to add an Async when there *is* an `async` modifier but doesn't tell what to do when there *isn't* any.

The `async` modifier is really not a part of the method's signature and you could easily accomplish the exact same behavior without it. If you look at the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) you wouldn't find a reference to the specific `async` modifier, but to the more broad definition of an `async` method.

In the .Net framework itself, you can't even know which Async method actually uses the `async` modifier. A lot (if not most) return `TaskCompletionSource.Task` to allow you (as a user) to use `async-await`. For example, this is [`Stream.WriteAsync`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#646bf77f3c9e8556):

```
public virtual Task WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // If cancellation was requested, bail early with an already completed task.
    // Otherwise, return a task that represents the Begin/End methods.
    return cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested
                ? Task.FromCancellation(cancellationToken)
                : BeginEndWriteAsync(buffer, offset, count);
}
```

Comment: "To be technical about it, the passage you quoted tells you to add an Async when there is an async modifier but doesn't tell what to do when there isn't any." That sums it up entirely.