# Tasks on type/interface contracts - guidelines?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, async-await, task

Simple question: Are there any guidelines, either published by Microsoft itself or a common practice regarding to declaring tasks on type and interface contracts?

So far, I've seen many different approaches:

Synchronous and asynchronous using TAP (most .NET types):

```
 void DoSomething();
 Task DoSomethingAsync();
```

TAP only:

```
 Task DoSomething(); // notice, no 'Async' member naming
```

Split contracts:

```
 interface IDoSomething {

 }

 interface IDoSomethingSync : IDoSomething {
     void DoSomething();
 }

 interface IDoSomethingAsync: IDoSomething {
     Task DoSomething();
 }
```

...or finally, just making a contract without any tasks and leave it up to the consumer.

Is there an official way to declare this? For a while, I sticked to the first example since it's the most common one in the .NET framework, but even there it's sometimes not consistent because of legacy reasons.

Comment: Such question is off-topic either as search for off-site resources or opinion-based. It is also asked many times before - I think duplicate is good enough closure reason, but feel free to comment why question should be closed by itself.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I did a search prior to posting the question, however nothing useful came up. Also, this should not be option-based as I am specifically asking for a guideline (preferably by Microsoft itself), so either there is one I was unable to find or there is none. I don't think the question you linked/marked is a duplicate because the OP there is asking for naming conventions, not general interface design guidelines.

Comment: artganify claims that this question is search for guidance and not duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24766651/interface-naming-convention-for-method-returning-task - re-opened(probably not for long).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, TAP naming conventions always do end in `Async`. There are a few exceptions to this rule, mainly on the `Task` type.

The first question you have to answer is: is this an operation that includes I/O? (Or, for interfaces, is this an operation that is *likely* going to have an asynchronous implementation?) If yes, then the method should have an asynchronous signature.

There is usually no need for matching synchronous signatures, unless you need them for backwards compatibility reasons. Note that most of the Desktop .NET APIs include both synchronous and asynchronous versions *for backwards compatibility*; the newer types (e.g., UWP, .NET Core) only have asynchronous (for I/O operations).

Stephen Toub wrote a couple of classic blog posts [Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx) and [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx). Spoiler alert: the answer to both is "no".

Comment: Very interesting articles, both make a lot of sense in case of wrapping sync to async and vice-versa. The only thing that's still unclear to me is the statement you made regarding to interfaces: "is this an operation that is likely going to have an asynchronous implementation?" Can we know for sure? Domain-related repositories for example should never expose features from their infrastructure implementation and in-memory-repositories (for testing purposes) certainly don't need resource intensive IO. So woulnd't it be better to hide the fact that operations might be running asynchronously?

Comment: @artganify: It's the same design problem as `IDisposable`. How can an interface know whether *any* of its implementations need to be disposed?Both disposal and asynchrony could be treated as implementation details in an ideal world; but it's not possible on C#/.NET.

Comment: I never thought about that, interesting. But that could also be solved by exposing a property which tells the consumer whether the implementation requires disposal, the same way ICollection for instances has a "IsReadOnly".